# C# input integer and char one line

Tags: c#, string, input, integer

### input integer and char in one line. This format is (5s)

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
{
    int number ,char n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());                                   
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: the term to research is *parse* but it would be easier to input one at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as a string and then substring and parse to the two variables

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int number = int.Parse(input.Substring(0,1));

for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int number = int.Parse(input.Substring(0,1));
    char n = char.Parse(input.Substring(1));                                   
}
```

Comment: Can we use int.parse and char.parse directly? won't it fail if someone enters "A 1" as input

Comment: Assuming the format will always be "5s" it can be used directly

Comment: I agree with you there, what if mistakenly someone enters "s5"?Won't parse break the code :p

Comment: Without really knowing what he is trying to do i can only speculate;)

Comment: after -2 he is never coming back :D

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
        string entry;
        entry = Console.ReadLine();
        int num;
        if (int.TryParse(entry, out num))
           {
             // it's a integer
            }
        else{
             // it's a string
            }
      }
```

I am not sure what is your actual intent of doing this.
But what you can do is, read the input and try to parse it to Integer.
If it is parsed then it is integer and you can use it the way you intent to.
If it is not parsed then that is probably a string and that's how you can differentiate.